# Using Makefiles for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, makefile

I would like to do the following:

```
start:
    @echo start the server

stop:
    @echo stop the server

test1: start stop
    @echo do test1

test2: start stop
    @echo do test2

test-all: test1 test2
```

But I have two problems:

1. How to specify `pre-` and `post-rules` in makefiles? All rules seem to be `pre-` in makefiles. In this case I want `stop` to be run at the end of each test.
2. How to force make to run the `start` and `stop` rules, even if it has already run them? The start/stop cycle needs to be done for *each* of the single-tests, so that when I run `make test-all`, `start` and `stop` are called for each test, not just once for the first test which requires them.

Answer (score 1):

```
test1:
    @echo start the server
    @echo do test1
    @echo stop the server

test2:
    @echo start the server
    @echo do test2
    @echo stop the server

test-all: test1 test2
```

If that's too much redundancy (e.g. if you have many unit tests), you can define a ["canned" recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes):

```
define start-stop
    @echo start the server
    $(1)
    @echo stop the server
endef

test1:
    $(call start-stop, @echo do test 1)

test2:
    $(call start-stop, @echo do test 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I have many similar tests. I do not like the fact that this does not make use of the dependency system, and that it makes the whole thing difficult to read. Where are the dependencies here? They are `start` (pre) and `stop` (post), but from the syntax that you are using (`canned recipe`?) this is not at all clear. I was hoping that there would be a simple operator to specify *this is a dependency which must run when the rule has finished*, and another operator to say *run this dependency always, even if it has just been run a moment ago*

Comment: Something like: `test1: +start +@stop` where the operator `@` would mean *run this dependency when the rule has ended* and the operator `+` would mean *run this dependency every time*. I have just made up those operators, but something like that would make my tests very readable.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: Make's dependency handling is not the right tool for that job, because it simply doesn't work that way. There are other ways to do it in Make, but if readability is what you want, I don't think they'd be much of an improvement on this (unless this scheme is unreadable because of the complexity of your unit test recipes).

Comment: thanks for the comment. What other tool would you use to harness unit tests where bash-like syntax for the test description can be used?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: [GoogleTest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest) looks interesting, but if that didn't fit I would write a parser in my favorite scripting language.